# K8s pod count in Java

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am trying to find out if there is a possibility for a java application, running in a Kubernetes Pod, to know how many of the same pods are running in the cluster. I looked at the downward API, but there is no option to see the number of pods. I understand that this information normally shouldn't matter, but I need to get it to adjust some parameters of the application.

Comment: You can definitely get this info but you should first figure which count you want. Desired count? Current? Etc.

Comment: How might you react if this count changes (if the HorizontalPodAutoscaler starts or stops some, for example)?  Do they actually need to be running?  Reachable?

Comment: I want to get the current count.